# AutoCompletion pops up on focusIn but cannot set text in QLineEdit from selection

Tags: python, pyqt4, qcompleter

```
from PyQt4.Qt import Qt, QObject,QLineEdit
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

import utils

class DirLineEdit(QLineEdit, QtCore.QObject):
    """docstring for DirLineEdit"""

    def __init__(self):
        super(DirLineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.xmlDataObj = utils.ReadWriteCustomPathsToDisk()
        self.defaultList = self.xmlDataObj.xmlData().values()
        self._pathsList()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.completer().complete()

    def _pathsList(self):        
        completerList = QtCore.QStringList()
        for i in self.defaultList:
            completerList.append(QtCore.QString(i))
        lineEditCompleter = QtGui.QCompleter(completerList)
        self.setCompleter(lineEditCompleter)

    def __dirCompleter(self):
        dirModel = QtGui.QFileSystemModel() 
        dirModel.setRootPath(QtCore.QDir.currentPath()) 
        dirModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs | QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files) 
        dirModel.setNameFilterDisables(0) 
        completer = QtGui.QCompleter(dirModel, self)    
        completer.setModel(dirModel)
        completer.setCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive) 
        self.setCompleter(completer)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
smObj = DirLineEdit()
smObj.show()
app.exec_()
```

The above code works except I cannot set the text from the selection I make in the AutoComplete that pops up on focus in event .. Any idea why I am not able to make set text of the selected by completer ?

Comment: I have answered your question, but I would advise you to provide complete, runnable example code in future. It will greatly increase your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your reimplementation of `focusInEvent` does not call its baseclass method. You should always do this unless you are certain you want to completely override the default behaviour. In this particular case, it's also important to call the baseclass `focusInEvent` method *before* invoking the completer, because that will obviously re-take the focus.

Here's a working demo that fixes the problems in the example code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class LineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, strings, parent):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setCompleter(QtGui.QCompleter(strings, self))

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.QLineEdit.focusInEvent(self, event)
        self.completer().complete()

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        strings = 'one two three four five six seven eight'.split()
        self.edit1 = LineEdit(strings, self)
        self.edit2 = LineEdit(strings, self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit1)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. my second question is how do I change the completer from `_pathList` to `__dirCompleter` ? I want if user inputs / or any alphabet, instead of showing list of path I now want to do browsing to certain location ?